# What problems exploration robot needs to overcome?

Tags: robotic-missions, robotics

[Morphex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yn3FWb-vQQ4) is a hexapod robot which can walk, transform into a ball, roll in a controlled manner... To see it on another world like Mars several issues need to be solved. First it needs a power source, probably RTG, electronics that are radiation hardened, it needs to be scaled up to accommodate all the scientific instruments and the power source. What other obstacles need to overcome in order to see Morphex exploring other worlds?

Answer (score 2):

Thermal control, especially for the actuators. Communication. Vision. Elimination of captured/stuck foreign objects.

Comment: Protection against dust.